# Will repointing solve water leakage issue?

Tags: leak, garage, masonry, cinderblock

[image]I have a detached garage that is getting water leakage through the back wall. There are no leaks coming from the roof, in fact the roof was replaced within the last year.

The walls of the garage are cinder block, and there is cracking inside AND outside. Would repointing solve the water issues?

Separately, 2 companies contacted offered different approaches, and wondering how to chose between them.

The first company suggested repointing the outside walls where there are cracks. The second company suggested repointing the inside where there are cracks. Any advice on where to start

Thanks!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is part of this wall below grade?

Comment: @Machavity - no.

Comment: Some pics of the cracks (inside and out) would probably be useful. Broad view for context and a close up or two for the details.

Comment: @FreeMan - I've added a few inside pictures

Comment: Are there gutters or does the water run off the roof and down the outside of the walls?

Comment: There are no gutters along that back wall. There is also no roof overhang - its a flat (slight grade) rubber roof.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like the roof has a proper overhang to minimize water running down walls. A gutter would help but the mortar on the outside really needs to be fixed. Fixing the mortar on only the inside will trap the water in the blocks and cause freeze and thaw issues.

The moss is bad for the mortar as well. Kill and remove it.